# How to prevent users from emptying a numeral input box?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

The following routable component prevents users from emptying the input box. It is what I want.

```
@page "/"
@using System.Text.RegularExpressions

<p>Counter: @counter</p>

<input 
       type="number"
       @bind="counter"
       @bind:event="oninput"
       @onkeypress="OnKeyPress"
       @onkeypress:preventDefault="true" />

@code {

    private int counter;
    private void OnKeyPress(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == "+")
            counter++;
        else if (e.Key == "-")
            counter--;

        if (Regex.IsMatch(e.Key, "[0-9]"))
        {
            counter = int.Parse($"{counter}{e.Key}");
        }
    }
}
```

For some reasons, I have to bind but without `@bind` and `@bind:event` as follows.

```
@page "/"
@using System.Text.RegularExpressions

<p>Counter: @counter</p>
<input 
       type="number"
       value="@counter"
       @oninput="OnInput"
       @onkeypress="OnKeyPress"
       @onkeypress:preventDefault="true" />

@code {

    private int counter;
    private void OnInput(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Value.ToString() == string.Empty)
        {
            e.Value = "0";
            counter = int.Parse(e.Value.ToString());
        }
    }
    private void OnKeyPress(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == "+")
            counter++;
        else if (e.Key == "-")
            counter--;

        if (Regex.IsMatch(e.Key, "[0-9]"))
        {
            counter = int.Parse($"{counter}{e.Key}");
        }
    }
}
```

However, users are no longer prevented from emptying the input box.

## Question

How to prevent users from emptying the input box but without using `@bind` and `@bind:event`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is much better than the other answer, including using the minus and plus key:

```
@page "/"
@using System.Text.RegularExpressions

<input type="number"
       value="@counter"
       @oninput="EventCallback.Factory.CreateBinder<int>(this, __value => counter = __value, counter)"
       @onkeydown="OnKeyDown"
       @onkeypress="OnKeyPress"
       @onkeypress:preventDefault="true" />
   
@code {

    private int counter;


    private void OnKeyDown(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Key == "Backspace" && (counter.ToString().Length == 1))
        {
            counter = 1;
            return;
        }
               

    }
    private void OnKeyPress(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {


        if (e.Key == "+")
            counter++;
        else if (e.Key == "-")
            counter--;



        if (Regex.IsMatch(e.Key, "[0-9]"))
        {
            counter = int.Parse($"{counter}{e.Key}");
        }


    }

}
```

The following version manipulate the input entered as string, not as number. This is actually how the internals of the input type number works. On the whole, there is no huge difference between the two version except that this version uses string instead of numeric values.

```
@page "/"
@using System.Text.RegularExpressions

<input type="number"
       value="@counter"
       @oninput="OnInput"
       @onkeydown="OnKeyDown"
       @onkeypress="OnKeyPress"
       @onkeypress:preventDefault="true" />
<input type="number" />

@code {
    private string counter = "0";
    private void OnInput(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Value.ToString() == "")
        {
            counter = "0";
        }
        else
        {
            counter = args.Value.ToString();

        }
    }
    private void OnKeyDown(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == "Backspace" && counter.Length == 1)
        {
            // Note that I'm using here space, but you may use any
            // character and string as long as it is not "0".
            counter = " ";
        }

    }
    private void OnKeyPress(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Key == "+")
        {
            var num = int.Parse(counter.ToString());
            num++;
            counter = num.ToString();
        }
        else if (e.Key == "-")
        {
            var num = int.Parse(counter.ToString());
            num--;
            counter = num.ToString();
        }

        if (Regex.IsMatch(e.Key, "[0-9]"))
        {
            counter += int.Parse($"{e.Key}").ToString();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: @Artificial Stupidity, when I'm free, I'll implement this by deriving from the InputText component

Comment: Out of topic: Is there any good reason (from the code base authors' point of view) to use `string` instead of `enum` for `e.Key`? It is error  prone because we cannot take the advantage of compile-time checking, right?